# A generic DropDown implemented by ControlBuilder lost all attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, generics

Here I have a code using ControlBuilder to make DropDown control generic.

```
[ControlBuilder(typeof(EnumDropDownControlBuilder))]
public class EnumDropDown : DropDownList {
    private string _enumType;
    private bool _allowEmpty;

    public string EnumType {
        get { return _EnumType; }
        set { _EnumType = value; }
    }

    public bool AllowEmpty {
        get { return _allowEmpty; }
        set { _allowEmpty= value; }
    }
}

public class EnumDropDown<T> : EnumDropDown where T : struct {
    public EnumDropDown() {
        this.Items.Clear();
        if (AllowEmpty) this.Items.Add(new ListItem("", "__EMPTY__"));
        foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T))) {
            Items.Add(name);
        }
    }

    public new T SelectedValue {
        get {
            if (IsEmpty) throw new NullReferenceException();
            return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), base.SelectedValue, true);
        }
        set { base.SelectedValue = Enum.GetName(typeof(T), value); }
    }

    public bool IsEmpty {
        get {
            return base.SelectedValue == "__EMPTY__";
        }
        set { base.SelectedValue = Enum.GetName(typeof(T), value); }
    }
}

public class EnumDropDownControlBuilder : ControlBuilder {
    public override void Init(TemplateParser parser, ControlBuilder parentBuilder, Type type, string tagName, string id, IDictionary attribs) {

        string enumTypeName = (string)attribs["EnumType"];
        Type enumType = Type.GetType(enumTypeName);
        if (enumType == null) {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} cannot be found or is not an enumeration", enumTypeName));
        }
        Type dropDownType = typeof(EnumDropDown<>).MakeGenericType(enumType);
        base.Init(parser, parentBuilder, dropDownType, tagName, id, attribs);
    }
}
```

Sorry the program is too long to read cheerfully.

The question is, although I defined property *EnumType*, *AllowEmpty* in class **EnumDropDown**. Since the real object created by ControlBuilder is **EnumDropDown**, values of *EnumType*, *AllowEmpty* are always **null** and **false** in control object.
All attributes set in .aspx will be lost!

I can read attribute values of source tag in ControlBuilder.
But I have no any idea how can I copy the attributes to the generic control object.

anyone can give me some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so stupid that I tried to read value of properties in construtor `public EnumDropDown()` . Of course attributes are not setted since object is still constucting.

I rename constructor `public EnumDropDown()` to the method `public void OnInit(EventArgs e)`, and all problem are fixed.